# Is SQLite DB on iOS application limited to any size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

Can I stora more than 200 MB of data on a SQLite DB in iOS application.
Is there any size limitation for the database?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can store as many data as you want in a sqlite DB. Your are only limited by the device capacity.

Comment: I tried inserting into a table which has 45 columns in a for loop runs  from 0 to 300000, The data are inserted safely, On each insertion I was opening and closing the database, So It crashed up to the DB Size to be 1.5 GB

Comment: And One question, As you said, If My database stored with device capacity, Will app face performance issue.